# component is not a known element: in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I've restarted, uninstalled, reinstalled, everything. App builds and serves with no error. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does `EmperorButtonModule` export `emperor-button`? If so, try to restart VS Code. If it doesn't, it has to export it in the `exports` array for other modules `import`ing it to have access to it.

Comment: What Angular version do you have? Is Angular language server running?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the correct selector is in fact emperor-button.  By default it would be app-emperor-button so that is the first thing I'd check.
2. If the component lives in your root module (AppModule), then it has to be in the declarations array.

Comment: Yep it's there. I can see it in node_modules 

`static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<ButtonComponent, "emperor-button", never, { "uiButtonType": "uiButtonType"; "type": "type"; "color": "color"; "pillSelected": "pillSelected"; "tooltipPlacement": "tooltipPlacement"; "disabled": "disabled"; "ariaLabel": "ariaLabel"; "id": "id"; "tooltip": "tooltip"; "closeTooltip": "closeTooltip"; }, { "click": "click"; }, never, ["*"]>;`